# video.js auto quality selector

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am rendering video to page.

Now my requirement is to play video based on network bandwidth.

I achieved ABR(Adaptive Bitrate) using video.js & videojs-contrib-hls plugin

Now , I want to add quality selector button for video i.e first it auto select video quality based on network bandwidth.

And also want to give option to select quality , but first it must select auto quality.

Please see attached screen shot which give you exact idea about what I want to do

[image]

**Note :**
I do not want to enable flash & video should be played in all browsers.
If there is other library than also please let me know so that i can use that also.
I tried with videojs-resolution-switcher plugin , which is not work for me.

Comment: Hey, it does appear a little that you're mixing two concepts - the idea of Auto is that the user doesn't actually get to select and this option usually utilizes something like DASH or HLS. The selectable fixed bitrates however, usually correspond to individual files in a full format, e.g. mp4. 

So question is what do you want to do - do you actually have the same video in mp4 resolutions, or do you want to rely on HLS/DASH in both cases, and basically "force" the user into a certain bitrate within the adaptive algorithm if they select a fixed bitrate?

Comment: did you find the answer? i want to auto select video quality based on network bandwidth, how can i do it i use this package now https://github.com/silvermine/videojs-quality-selector